# save and compile automatically

Tags: emacs

GNU 23.1.1

By clicking the F5 button I can compile my project. However, I want to extend this so that any unsaved work would be saved and then compiled.

Normally I just do C-x-s to save then click F5. But can I add a line that will save without having to ask me do I want to save then it will compile, all done automatically?

```
; Compile program using <F5>
; Save all unsaved files here, then compile
(global-set-key [f5] 'compile)
```

Hope you understand me?

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: I think you are asking how to get Emacs to automatically save whenever you compile? Check my answer below for how to do this.

Comment: Although a bit different from what you're asking for, this recipe for adding an `after-save-hook` did the trick for me - http://rtime.felk.cvut.cz/~sojka/blog/compile-on-save/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `(save-some-buffers 1)` to save all buffers containing changes.

Wrap it up with a function together with `compile` like so:

```
(defun save-all-and-compile ()
  (save-some-buffers 1)
  (compile compile-command))
```

Then set F5 to run this function instead of plain compile.

Use `(save-some-buffers)` (no argument) if you prefer Emacs to ask you about each buffer to be saved. Also, you might want to make the compilation-command customisable, as it is with `compile`... I'll leave that to you though.

---

## Getting it to work

You also have to add `(interactive)`, see full example below.

```
(defun save-all-and-compile ()
  (interactive)
  (save-some-buffers 1)
  (compile compile-command))
(global-set-key [f5] 'save-all-and-compile)
```

Comment: I would recommend that you use a key (or a combination) in your main typing area rather than something out of the way like F5 to do this though.

Comment: Getting this error `command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, save-all-and-compile` when typing F5 after adding this line `(global-set-key [f5] 'save-all-and-compile)` for binding the key. I'm on Emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: You need to add `(interactive)` as first line of the `defun`.

Answer (score 24):

Put `(setq compilation-ask-about-save nil)` in your `.emacs` to automatically save (without asking) before you compile or recompile.

Answer (score 16):

On every Emacs I use (from the 19.34 to 24), compile do ask for saving unsaved buffer before proceeding. I'm very surprise it is not the case for you.

So just M-x compile (f5 for you) will ask to save unsaved buffer.

you can customize compilation-ask-about-save to nil if you want compile to unconditionally save all buffer, or let it to it's default non nil value if you want to be asked.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It does ask you to save. However, I would prefer not to be prompted but to save anything on each compile. Normally I always have more than 1 buffer open and I would just like to save anything without being prompted for each compile.

Comment: then customize compilation-ask-about-save. It's just for this (save all buffer with no asking prior to compilation)?